# On the eigenvalues / properties of a specific matrix.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm not sure how to better phrase the title of the question, because I don't know the specific name of the matrix I am after, but I want to consider matrices of the form
$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & b& b&b & \cdots & b\\
b & a & b& b&b&\cdots & b\\
\vdots\\
b&b&b&b&b&\cdots & a
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
$$
that is, the diagonal entries are identical, and all the off diagonals are all the same. The most obvious example for when this occurs is when $a=1, b=0$ and you obtain the identity matrix. I just want to know if there is anything we can see about the eigenvalues of this matrix, or if there are any special properties about this matrix itself.

EDIT: The matrix size itself is $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ where $m$ is not necessarily equal to $n$.

Comment: Assuming the matrix is $n\times n$, clearly $\left(a+(n-1)b, \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix}_{n\times 1}\right)$is an eigenpair of the matrix.

Comment: Do you know its multiplicity?

Comment: Did you try with $x = \alpha \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ \vdots \\1\end{bmatrix} + x'$ ? with $x'$ orthogonal to $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: See [Determinant of a specially structured matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/determinant-of-a-specially-structured-matrix) or [Prove determinant of $n \times n$ matrix is $(a+(n-1)b)(a-b)^{n-1}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757320/prove-determinant-of-n-times-n-matrix-is-an-1ba-bn-1). Although both questions are about determinant. The eigenvalues are evident from the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the matrix you mentioned has dimension $N \times N$, then its eigenvalues are

$\lambda_{1}=\lambda_{2}= \cdots =\lambda_{N-1}=(a-b)$ and

$\lambda_{N}=(a+(N-1)b)$