# Determinant of m by m Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How would you find the determinant of an $m \times m$ matrix which has $m$ as every diagonal entry and $-1$ as every non diagonal entry?

Comment: Add $1/m$ times row $1$ to all other rows.  Then use cofactor expansion along the first column.

Comment: I believe the eigenvalues would be $m-1$ $(m+1)$'s and 1 $1$, so the product would be $(m+1)^{m-1}$. Can anyone verify this?

Comment: This might prove useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757320/prove-determinant-of-n-times-n-matrix-is-an-1ba-bn-1/757342#757342

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be the $m\times m$ matrix with $0$ on the diagonal and $-1$ elsewhere.  The determinant you want can be found by evaluating
$$\det(A-\lambda I)$$
and then substituting $\lambda=-m$.  Now it is easy to see that if $\lambda=1$ then $A-\lambda I$ has a row echelon form with $m-1$ zero rows.  Therefore $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with geometric multiplicity $m-1$ and hence algebraic multiplicity at least $m-1$.  The last eigenvalue $\mu$ is found from the trace,
$$(m-1)(1)+\mu={\rm trace}(A)=0$$
and so $\mu=-(m-1)$.  So $A$ has characteristic polynomial
$$\det(A-\lambda I)=(-1)^m(\lambda-1)^{m-1}(\lambda+m-1)\ ,$$
and the determinant of your matrix is
$$\det(A+mI)=(-1)^m(-m-1)^{m-1}(-m+m-1)=(m+1)^{m-1}\ .$$

Comment: Great trick using the trace to find the last eigenvalue!

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix is can be written as a rank $1$ perturbation to identity
$$(m+1)I_m - \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ \vdots\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1& 1& \vdots& 1\end{bmatrix}$$
Now make use of [Sylvester determinant theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem):
$$\det(I+UV^T) = \det(I+V^TU)$$to obtain what you want after appropriate scaling.